# Join a table with itself as a concept

Tags: join, self-join

I am not understanding the summary that the video learning I am doing has given me. The explaining of why I would join a table with itself is unclear. I am brand new at this and have been doing well up to this concept. Thank you for any help.

I thought I would just choose more columns.

Comment: for example if you want to know if there are duplicates